# FullSimplify command not showing any output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebra

I am trying to `FullSimplify` an expression and in the end I am not getting any output displayed. The process runs for sometime and stops after making a sound. The code goes like this.

First I define some coefficients:

```
a = 2282/2880; b = -546/2880; c = 89/2880; d = -3/2880; e = -1/2880;
ai = 1821/2880; bi = -461/2880 ; ci = 85/2880 ; di = -4 /2880; ei = -1/2880;
```

Then I define two 3D variables namely `yJz` and `yKz` at various `i,j,k` indices using `For` loops. They both are functions of `y` and `z`.

```
For[k = -5, k <= 5, k++,
 For[j = -5, j <= 5, j++,
  For[i = -5, i <= 5, i++, 
   yJz[i, j, k] = 
      (a*(y[i, j + 1, k] - y[i, j - 1, k]) + 
       b*(y[i, j + 2, k] - y[i, j - 2, k]) + 
       c*(y[i, j + 3, k] - y[i, j - 3, k]) + 
       d*(y[i, j + 4, k] - y[i, j - 4, k]) + 
       e*(y[i, j + 5, k] - y[i, j - 5, k]))*z[i, j, k]]]]

For[k = -5, k <= 5, k++,
 For[j = -5, j <= 5, j++,
  For[i = -5, i <= 5, i++, 
   yKz[i, j, k] = 
      (a*(y[i, j, k + 1] - y[i, j, k - 1]) + 
       b*(y[i, j, k + 2] - y[i, j, k - 2]) + 
       c*(y[i, j, k + 3] - y[i, j, k - 3]) + 
       d*(y[i, j, k + 4] - y[i, j, k - 4]) + 
       e*(y[i, j, k + 5] - y[i, j, k - 5]))*z[i, j, k]]]]
```

Using the above defined `yJz` and `yKz`, I compute `Ix` at various `i` indices as follows:

```
j = 0; k = 0;
For[i = -5, i <= 5, i++, 
 Ix[i, 0, 0] = 
    (a*(yJz[i, j, k + 1] - yJz[i, j, k - 1]) + 
     b*(yJz[i, j, k + 2] - yJz[i, j, k - 2]) + 
     c*(yJz[i, j, k + 3] - yJz[i, j, k - 3]) + 
     d*(yJz[i, j, k + 4] - yJz[i, j, k - 4]) + 
     e*(yJz[i, j, k + 5] - yJz[i, j, k - 5])) - 
    (a*(yKz[i, j + 1, k] - yKz[i, j - 1, k]) + 
     b*(yKz[i, j + 2, k] - yKz[i, j - 2, k]) + 
     c*(yKz[i, j + 3, k] - yKz[i, j - 3, k]) + 
     d*(yKz[i, j + 4, k] - yKz[i, j - 4, k]) + 
     e*(yKz[i, j + 5, k] - yKz[i, j - 5, k]))]
```

Finally I evaluate `Ixph` at `i=-1` and `i=0`

```
For[i = -1, i <= 0, i++, 
 Ixph[i, 0, 
   0] = (ai*(Ix[i + 1, 0, 0] + Ix[i, 0, 0]) + 
    bi*(Ix[i + 2, 0, 0] + Ix[i - 1, 0, 0]) + 
    ci*(Ix[i + 3, 0, 0] + Ix[i - 2, 0, 0]) + 
    di*(Ix[i + 4, 0, 0] + Ix[i - 3, 0, 0]) + 
    ei*(Ix[i + 5, 0, 0] + Ix[i - 4, 0, 0]))]
```

Now having defined everything, when I tried to execute `FullSimplify[(Ixph[0, 0, 0] - Ixph[-1, 0, 0])]` Mathematica dosen't show any output. I am expecting a value of `0` as an output here (I am not sure though). The values of `y` and `z` are arbitrary and they should all get cancelled out in the end.

I am confused why `FullSimplify` dosen't show any output.

Comment: `FullSimplify` can be extremely slow for very large expressions like yours, which has over 33000 symbols, numbers, operators.  Since you have large fractions with a lot of similarity I tried `Together[Ixph[0,0,0]-Ixph[-1,0,0]]` which is far faster and gives a result with less than 20000 symbols, numbers, operators, but still didn't reduce it to zero. `Simplify` is FAR faster than `FullSimplify` on huge expressions, but I still couldn't get it to zero. You can look up `LeafCount` to see how I counted the number of items in your expressions.

Comment: There is also [PossibleZeroQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html).

Comment: Seems like the issue is due to large number of symbols, Is there a simple or efficient way to simplify the final expression which could give some output?

Comment: Can I get rid of LOTS of symbols and make this FAR faster and still get a correct answer? I don't know. You must understand that I don't trust almost anything. That applies to this: `Ixph[0,0,0]-Ixph[-1,0,0]//.{y[p_,q_,r_]->ToString[y[p,q,r]],z[p_,q_,r_]->ToString[z[p,q,r]]}` which almost instantly returns zero. Did that correctly calculate the result was zero? Or is that some side effect of using strings in combination with the rest of your calculations? If I repeat this with `Ixph[0,0,0]+7-Ixph[-1,0,0]-Pi//.{...}` then it returns `7-Pi` How can you convince yourself this is actually correct?

Comment: I just found out that, using the `PossibleZeroQ` command, the expression `Ixph[0,0,0]-Ixph[-1,0,0]`  in fact is not equal to zero. You can also double check this by extracting the coefficent of `z[-5, -5, 0]` through `Coefficient[(Ixph[0, 0, 0] - Ixph[-1, 0, 0]), z[-5, -5, 0]]`. The string based operation does not seem 100% legit, but I am still not sure.

Comment: To try to make up for my string mistake, looking at `Numerator[Together[Ixph[0,0,0]-Ixph[-1,0,0]]]` (since that denominator is a constant) shows `- y[-5,-5,-5]*z[-5,-5,0]+y[-5,-5,-5]*z[-5,0,-5]+...` where every `y[a,b,c]` appears to show up exactly twice, each multiplied by a different `z[p,q,r]` That seems to show my string trick failed and the sum is not zero unless each `y[]` or `z[]` has some very special values.